# Is there a query that can do this?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table :

```
col1       col2   col3    col4      col5    col6      col7   col8   col9
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-02-22  A      B       C          D     625.2      E       K    448
2018-02-22  A      B       C          D     625.2      F       L    5.35
2018-02-22  A      B       C          D     625.2      G       M    35.71
2018-02-22  A      B       C          D     625.2      H       N    87.39
2018-02-22  A      B       C          D     625.2      I       O    25.11
2018-02-22  A      B       C          D     625.2      J       P    33.93
2018-02-22  A1     B1      C1         D1    14849.5    E1      K1   13294.21
2018-02-22  A1     B1      C1         D1    14849.5    F1      L1   427.03
2018-02-22  A1     B1      C1         D1    14849.5    G1      M1   631.85
2018-02-22  A1     B1      C1         D1    14849.5    H1      N1   326.07
2018-02-22  A1     B1      C1         D1    14849.5    I1      O1   146.36
2018-02-22  A1     B1      C1         D1    14849.5    J1      P1   6.86
```

Result :

```
col1       col2   col3    col4      col5    col6      col7   col8   col9
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-02-22  A      B       C          D     625.2      E       K    448
2018-02-22                                  625.2      F       L    5.35
2018-02-22                                  625.2      G       M    35.71
2018-02-22                                  625.2      H       N    87.39
2018-02-22                                  625.2      I       O    25.11
2018-02-22                                  625.2      J       P    33.93
2018-02-22  A1     B1      C1         D1    14849.5    E1      K1   13294.21
2018-02-22                                  14849.5    F1      L1   427.03
2018-02-22                                  14849.5    G1      M1   631.85
2018-02-22                                  14849.5    H1      N1   326.07
2018-02-22                                  14849.5    I1      O1   146.36
2018-02-22                                  14849.5    J1      P1   6.86
```

Comment: Maybe.  Give some more details about what it is doing.

Comment: MySQL or SQL-Server? The solution will be different for each database.

Comment: `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ?

Comment: You need to explain your problem better

Comment: This looks more like an output issue than something to do with a query.

Comment: why not handle that in your front end screen or reporting ?

Comment: You can use user variables to hold the values of the `col2` through `col5` from the previous row. If the current value is the same, return a blank instead of the value of the column.

Comment: SQL Server , the point is to ''merge''  col2 to col 6 where the values are the same , but leave the other columns as they are .

Answer (score 2):

If there is any unique column in your table over which we can sort data then we can use `LAG` function as shown below -

```
declare @x table (id int, col1 varchar(10))

insert into @x (id, col1)
select 1, 'A' union all
select 2, 'A' union all
select 3, 'A' union all
select 4, 'A' union all
select 5, 'B' union all
select 6, 'B'

select
    id,
    col1,
    (case when col1 = lag(col1) over (order by id asc) then '' else col1 end) as NewCol
from @x
```

Output-

```
id  col1    NewCol
1   A       A
2   A   
3   A   
4   A   
5   B       B
6   B
```